# Update DOM while iterating over Backbone Collection?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, coffeescript

So I am trying to display a loading bar when rendering very large collections. I have a placeholder for the loading bar when the page initially loads, and I am trying to update it like this:

```
addAll: 
  @collection.each(((obj, index) ->
    @addOne(obj, index)), this
  )

addOne: (obj, index) ->
  percent_complete = ((index / @collection.length) * 100)
  $(".loading_bar").width("#{percent_complete}%")
  # Proceed with rendering, create the view, etc
```

The problem here is that the DOM isnt updated until the `addAll` function completes. I have a feeling that this is me not understanding some basic JS fundamentals. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you are missing something fundamental: the browser won't do any of its own work until your code returns control to the browser.

Consider some code like this:

```
collection = [1..1000]

addOne = (index) ->
  $('#n').text(index + 1)
  percent_complete = ((index + 1) / collection.length) * 100
  $("#bar").width("#{percent_complete}%")

addOne(i) for e,i in collection  
console.log('done')
```

You'll see a brief pause and then `#bar` and `#n` will be updated and `done` will appear in the console. Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/f5qKV/ (you might need to increase the 1000 to make things more obvious).

However, if you return control to the browser with [`setTimeout(..., 0)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.setTimeout) on each iteration:

```
collection = [1..1000]

addOne = (index) ->
  $('#n').text(index + 1)
  percent_complete = ((index + 1) / collection.length) * 100
  $("#bar").width("#{percent_complete}%")

i = 0
timeOut = ->
    if(i == collection.length)
        console.log('done')
        return
    addOne(i++)
    setTimeout(timeOut, 0)
setTimeout(timeOut, 0)
```

you'll be able to see `#bar` and `#n` changing and then you'll see `done` in the console when everything has finished. Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/UCbY8/1/

Note that the `setTimeout` version uses the `setTimeout` callback to trigger the next timeout, that ensures that everything happens in the same order as they would in a simple `for` or `each` loop.

The lesson is that you have to add some old-school pseudo cooperative multi-tasking hacks into the mix if you want to use that kind of progress indicator.

---

Handing control back to the browser also leaves you open to user interaction when you're not expecting it. You might want to add a general UI blocker to keep people from clicking on things while you're working if you go this route.